# How to convert buffer to an Image to display on the frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, blob, buffer

I have the image saved in the DB as BLOB datatype

I'm using nodejs with express and I'm using multer library to upload the images

`if (req.file) { userProfile.profilePhoto = req.file } await userProfile.save()`

this is what I'm doing on the frontend I recieve the profilePhoto as

`profilePhoto: { type: "Buffer", data: (15)[string of numbers] }`

I tried converting it to a base64 cause I looked other question related to this but didn't work for me I did it on the client side

`import {Buffer} from "buffer" const base64 = Buffer.from( result.data.profilePhoto.data, "binary" ).toString("base64");`
which gives me a weird string like this W29iamVjdCBPYmplY3Rd

I want to pass a link to the src attribute I don't know how to do it any help would be appreciated

also should I handle the conversion in the backend ? what would be the best

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
import {Buffer} from "buffer" 
const base64 = Buffer.from(result.data.profilePhoto.data,
"binary" ).toString("base64");
```

will return a string "W29iamVjdCBPYmplY3Rd".
Append `"data:image/png;base64,"` prefix to it... and add that to src of your image in the frontend..

Handling the same can be done in backend also....

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. but thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

NodeJs.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/image', (req, res) => {
   // Read the image buffer from a file or database
   const imageBuffer = fs.readFileSync('path/to/image.jpg');

   // Send the image buffer as a response
   res.send(imageBuffer);
 });

 app.listen(3000, () => {
   console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
 });
```

Frontend

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Image Display Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <img id="image" alt="Image">
<script>
 fetch('/image')
  .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
  .then(buffer => {
    const image = new Blob([buffer], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
    const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(image);
    
    // Set the data URL as the image source
    document.getElementById('image').src = imageUrl;
  })
  .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching image:', error));
 </script>
 </body>`enter code here`
 </html>
```

My opinion: I store all links in backend (somewhere like S3 bucket). And I give only links to front

Answer (score 0):

```
if (req.file) {
  console.log(req.file)
  userProfile.profilePhoto = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path)
  fs.writeFileSync(
    path.resolve(__dirname, '..', `images/${req.file.originalname}`),
    userProfile.profilePhoto
  )
}
```

This solved my problem before I was storing the req.file in the db now I'm storing the image using node fs module.